# 'shared_ptr'; 'scoped_ptr' error ruby passenger

Tags: ruby, apache2, passenger

I getting an error while install passenger module on apache

```
In file included from ext/common/AccountsDatabase.h:32:
ext/common/Account.h:171:9: error: unknown type name 'shared_ptr'; did you mean 'scoped_ptr'?
typedef shared_ptr<Account> AccountPtr;
        ^~~~~~~~~~
        scoped_ptr
ext/boost/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.hpp:39:25: note: 'scoped_ptr' declared here
template<class T> class scoped_ptr // noncopyable
                        ^
In file included from ext/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/aggregate.cpp:5:
In file included from ext/common/AccountsDatabase.cpp:31:
In file included from ext/common/AccountsDatabase.h:32:
ext/common/Account.h:171:19: error: expected unqualified-id
typedef shared_ptr<Account> AccountPtr;
                  ^
In file included from ext/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/aggregate.cpp:5:
In file included from ext/common/AccountsDatabase.cpp:31:
In file included from ext/common/AccountsDatabase.h:33:
In file included from ext/common/ServerInstanceDir.h:42:
ext/common/Utils.h:86:22: error: unknown type name 'shared_ptr'; did you mean 'scoped_ptr'?
template<typename T> shared_ptr<T>
                     ^~~~~~~~~~
                     scoped_ptr
ext/boost/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.hpp:39:25: note: 'scoped_ptr' declared here
template<class T> class scoped_ptr // noncopyable
                        ^
In file included from ext/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/aggregate.cpp:5:
In file included from ext/common/AccountsDatabase.cpp:31:
In file included from ext/common/AccountsDatabase.h:33:
In file included from ext/common/ServerInstanceDir.h:42:
ext/common/Utils.h:86:32: error: expected unqualified-id
template<typename T> shared_ptr<T>
                               ^
ext/common/Utils.h:354:34: error: unknown type name 'function'
void runAndPrintExceptions(const function<void ()> &func, bool toAbort);
                                 ^
ext/common/Utils.h:354:42: error: expected ')'
void runAndPrintExceptions(const function<void ()> &func, bool toAbort);
                                         ^
ext/common/Utils.h:354:27: note: to match this '('
void runAndPrintExceptions(const function<void ()> &func, bool toAbort);
                          ^
ext/common/Utils.h:355:34: error: unknown type name 'function'
void runAndPrintExceptions(const function<void ()> &func);
                                 ^
ext/common/Utils.h:355:42: error: expected ')'
void runAndPrintExceptions(const function<void ()> &func);
                                         ^
ext/common/Utils.h:355:27: note: to match this '('
void runAndPrintExceptions(const function<void ()> &func);
                          ^
In file included from ext/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/aggregate.cpp:5:
In file included from ext/common/AccountsDatabase.cpp:31:
In file included from ext/common/AccountsDatabase.h:33:
ext/common/ServerInstanceDir.h:191:10: error: unknown type name 'shared_ptr'; did you mean 'scoped_ptr'?
        typedef shared_ptr<Generation> GenerationPtr;
                ^~~~~~~~~~
                scoped_ptr
ext/boost/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.hpp:39:25: note: 'scoped_ptr' declared here
template<class T> class scoped_ptr // noncopyable
                        ^
In file included from ext/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/aggregate.cpp:5:
In file included from ext/common/AccountsDatabase.cpp:31:
In file included from ext/common/AccountsDatabase.h:33:
ext/common/ServerInstanceDir.h:191:20: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
        typedef shared_ptr<Generation> GenerationPtr;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
ext/common/ServerInstanceDir.h:291:2: error: unknown type name 'GenerationPtr'; did you mean 'Generation'?
        GenerationPtr newGeneration(bool userSwitching, const string &defaultUser,
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Generation
ext/common/ServerInstanceDir.h:58:8: note: 'Generation' declared here
        class Generation: public noncopyable {
              ^
ext/common/ServerInstanceDir.h:309:2: error: unknown type name 'GenerationPtr'; did you mean 'Generation'?
        GenerationPtr getGeneration(unsigned int number) const {
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Generation
ext/common/ServerInstanceDir.h:58:8: note: 'Generation' declared here
        class Generation: public noncopyable {
              ^
ext/common/ServerInstanceDir.h:313:2: error: unknown type name 'GenerationPtr'; did you mean 'Generation'?
        GenerationPtr getNewestGeneration() const {
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Generation
ext/common/ServerInstanceDir.h:58:8: note: 'Generation' declared here
        class Generation: public noncopyable {
              ^
ext/common/ServerInstanceDir.h:267:4: error: unknown type name 'GenerationPtr'; did you mean 'Generation'?
                        GenerationPtr newestGeneration;
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                        Generation
ext/common/ServerInstanceDir.h:58:8: note: 'Generation' declared here
        class Generation: public noncopyable {
              ^
ext/common/ServerInstanceDir.h:267:18: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Passenger::ServerInstanceDir::Generation'
                        GenerationPtr newestGeneration;
                                      ^
ext/common/ServerInstanceDir.h:58:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
        class Generation: public noncopyable {
              ^
ext/common/ServerInstanceDir.h:66:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 0 were provided
                Generation(const string &serverInstanceDir, unsigned int number) {
                ^
ext/common/ServerInstanceDir.h:295:3: error: unknown type name 'GenerationPtr'; did you mean 'Generation'?
                GenerationPtr newestGeneration = getNewestGeneration();
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                Generation
ext/common/ServerInstanceDir.h:58:8: note: 'Generation' declared here
        class Generation: public noncopyable {
              ^
ext/common/ServerInstanceDir.h:58:8: error: base class 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable' has private copy constructor
        class Generation: public noncopyable {
              ^
ext/boost/noncopyable.hpp:27:7: note: declared private here
      noncopyable( const noncopyable& );
      ^
ext/common/ServerInstanceDir.h:295:36: note: implicit copy constructor for 'Passenger::ServerInstanceDir::Generation' first required here
                GenerationPtr newestGeneration = getNewestGeneration();
                                                 ^
ext/common/ServerInstanceDir.h:297:24: warning: comparison between NULL and non-pointer ('Passenger::ServerInstanceDir::Generation' and NULL) [-Wnull-arithmetic]
                if (newestGeneration != NULL) {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~
ext/common/ServerInstanceDir.h:297:24: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('Passenger::ServerInstanceDir::Generation' and 'long')
                if (newestGeneration != NULL) {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~
ext/common/StaticString.h:288:1: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Passenger::ServerInstanceDir::Generation' to 'const string' (aka
      'const basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') for 1st argument
operator!=(const string &other, const StaticString &str) {
^
ext/common/StaticString.h:293:1: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Passenger::ServerInstanceDir::Generation' to 'const char *' for 1st argument
operator!=(const char *other, const StaticString &str) {
^
In file included from ext/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/aggregate.cpp:5:
In file included from ext/common/AccountsDatabase.cpp:31:
In file included from ext/common/AccountsDatabase.h:33:
ext/common/ServerInstanceDir.h:298:32: error: member reference type 'Passenger::ServerInstanceDir::Generation' is not a pointer; maybe you meant to use '.'?
                        newNumber = newestGeneration->getNumber() + 1;
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
                                                    .
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
1 warning and 20 errors generated.
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [g++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -fPIC -...]
/Users/msingh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@showroom/gems/passenger-3.0.15/build/cplusplus_support.rb:31:in `compile_cxx'
/Users/msingh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@showroom/gems/passenger-3.0.15/build/common_library.rb:126:in `block in define_common_library_task'
/Users/msingh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@showroom/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/msingh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@showroom/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => apache2 => ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so => ext/apache2/module_libpassenger_common.a => ext/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/aggregate.o
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

--------------------------------------------

It looks like something went wrong
```

I am getting this when do passenger-install-apache2-module on the app

Comment: I suspect these are not the first errors you see, and that there are more errors above this (i.e. missing header files). This is certainly not the full output of the build log.

Comment: This problem is solved by using passenger gem 5.0.6